# Using map with variable

Tags: python

I have str list

```
startDateTimes = ["2011/12/13 00:00","2011/12/13 03:00","2011/12/15 05:00"]
datetime.datetime.strptime(startDateTimes[0],'%Y/%m/%d %H:%M')
```

Now I want to use `strptime` for all items in list.

I think I should use `map` though, still not clear to me.

For example

```
map(datetime.datetime.strptime,startDateTimes)
```

Where should I put `%Y/%m/%d %H:%M`?

Comment: I consider closing of the question a bit harsh without additional explanation. As I understand, the approach suggest in the linked question is, to call map with 3 arguments, the `strptime`  function, an iterator delivering the data format (e. g. `itertools.repeat`) and the startDateTimes list.

Comment: Yes, Maybe it is me not getting the rules 100% and I agree that some questions would require minimal effort to find an answer but, at the end of the day, it is a "help"  forum and not a book. I myself think this did not deserve to be closed - for what it counts :-)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Why not a list comprehension?

```
[datetime.datetime.strptime(x, '%Y/%m/%d %H:%M') for x in startDateTimes]
```

You could use `map` like this:

```
def parse(x): return datetime.datetime.strptime(x, '%Y/%m/%d %H:%M')

list(map(parse, startDateTimes))
```

**OUTPUT**

```
[datetime.datetime(2011, 12, 13, 0, 0), datetime.datetime(2011, 12, 13, 3, 0), datetime.datetime(2011, 12, 15, 5, 0)]
```

You could clearly have a one-liner and move the definition of the `parse` function as a lambda within `map` - just wanted to make it clearer.

Comment: THank you , i use comprehension, it works well for this purpose. Using `map` needs two lines.

Answer (score 1):

You can use a lambda here

```py
map(lambda dt: datetime.datetime.strptime(dt,'%Y/%m/%d %H:%M'),startDateTimes)
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use [functools.partial](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functools.html#functools.partial) for this, it allows you to create a function which will apply given arguments by default. Example:

```py
from functools import partial

dates = map(partial(datetime.datetime.strptime, format='%Y/%m/%d %H:%M'), startDateTimes)
```